# HTML 5 Doctype creates extra space for justified horizontal unorderd list menu

Tags: css, html

Okay I have been attempting to find the best way to evenly space `<li>` menu items horizontally for a variable amount of menu items.

I have found that applying `text-align:justify` to the containing div, `display:inline` to the `ul`, `display:inline-block` to the `<li>`, and adding a `span` after the `ul` with:

```
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
height:0
```

will generate the desired effect.

However, there is a lot of inexplicable extra space under the ul. After many hours of headaches I figured out that it appears only in an html file with an HTML 5 Doctype. If it has the old XHTML Transitional Doctype it displays exactly as expected. My question is: why is this extra space there and how do I get rid of it?

Here's the markup I've been toying with:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #666;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav ul {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="">texttexttext</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">tex</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">texttext</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">text</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">text</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">texttexttext</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">texttexttext</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">texttext</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frhxS/10/)

Comment: The span is unnecessary for styling this list. Try it the way I listed below. It looks great! ;) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/frhxS/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height:0` to the div with class nav, `line-height:1.2` to the ul and `vertical-align:top` to the span.

Also consider replacing the span with a `.nav:after` pseudo-element.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/frhxS/13/

The principle behind the changes is to remove the effect of the [strut](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#strut) on the two line boxes. The strut has no effect on the height of the line boxes when using XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype or the HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype but does set a minimum height for the line boxes when used with either the HTML5 doctype or the XHTML 1.0 Strict or HTML 4.01 Strict doctypes.

Comment: Hi, do you know why there is an area at the bottom of the grey bar that is unclickable, when it should be? It happens in latest Chrome for Windows (39.0.2171.71 m) but doesn't happen for latest Firefox for Windows (33.1.1) nor IE 10 (appears to be okay in browser mode for IE 8 and 9, too.) I solved it with making the anchors `position: relative;` but I'd prefer to know why it's happening, than just the hack to fix it.

Comment: @setek - Good question. To the best of my knowledge neither HTML or CSS precisely defines the click area of anchor elements. But the line box of the `:after` pseudo-element is overlaying the line box of the ul in Chrome for the area that isn't clickable. (the line-height is 0, but the glyphs extend outside that line height). One fix is to set the font-size of the nav element to 0 and give the ul a font-size in pixels. Then the glyphs as well as the line-height in the pseudo-element will be 0 height. `position:relative` is probably changing the paint order, to bring the anchor text to the top.

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks for that :) I don't like giving things a font-size too small, I know Safari has an "ignore font sizes smaller than 9pt" setting, so I don't like relying on it to work .. I'll just fudge the look with the `position: relative;` lol ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
 .nav ul{
    display:inline;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none; 
 }
```

instead of:

```
 .nav>ul{
    display:inline;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width property of the li to 12% and getting rid of the span element.

```
body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;  
    }
    .nav{
        width:900px;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:relative;
        text-align:justify;
        background-color:#666;
        white-space:no-wrap;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .nav>ul{
        display:inline;
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        list-style:none; 
     }
     .nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:1.2em;
    width: 12%;
    text-align:center;
 }
     .nav li a{
        display:inline-block;
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:10px;
     }
```

and

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li> <a href="">texttexttext</a></li>
<li> <a href="">tex</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">texttext</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">text</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">text</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">texttexttext</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">texttexttext</a> </li>
<li> <a href="">texttext</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but this ends up creating uneven spacing between the elements.

Comment: Plus I'm trying to create a solution that does not require a manual or scripted recalculation each time and item is added or deleted. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: This is not possible without the use of Javascript. You will always have to recalculate if you want to get a good looking list, unless you use the flex-box property. However, That will require a javascript plugin if you want to have backwards compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Let me ask you this, if you take the code I posted above and put it in an editor or run it in a browser with the XHTML 4 Transitional doctype does it display correctly without the extra space at the bottom? and not work for the HTML 5 Doctype?

Comment: You are correct. The reason is that you are using the span to assist with the layout styling and that is not the purpose of the span element. Anytime you are using an element for its unintended purpose, you run the risk of compatibility issues with other browsers or standard versions.

Comment: Very true. I have already created a javascript solution for assessing, sizing and spacing the elements but certain mobile devices don't consistently run the JS consistently but that's a whole other issue. Works beautifully on the desktop though. That's why I'm trying find a approach that uses less scripting.

Comment: Definitely, I found that the best solution for mobile is using media queries to deliver a different menu experience to mobile devices. I frequently move it to the bottom as a block level list with a width of 100% or nest it away in a drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

`.nav{ white-space:nowrap; }` not `white-space:no-wrap`. This will fix your problem

Comment: Oops, good eye but with the nowarp woking it actually breaks the justify. I removed it from the above code since it breaks it and I removed it on my local machine. Thanks

Comment: @DaveDavidD no it doesnt. The span does :) remove the span and everything is ok

Comment: If I remove the span the items will not stretch the full width of the container.